# Добавить строку из одного текстового файла в результат выполнения скрипта Ping

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, сеть, ping

Ребят подскажите как скрипт можно завершить. Имеется ip_list.txt. В нем список построчно записанный вида:

"Имя"

IP адрес.

Необходимо сделать таким образом чтоб на против Ip адреса прибавлялся "Имя" в файле "resultat_ping.txt"

```
import os
import time

results_file = open ("resultat_ping.txt", "w")
input_file = open ("ip_list.txt")
with input_file as file:

        ip_set = file.read().splitlines()  [1::2]
        for ip in ip_set:
                response = os.system((f"ping {ip} -w 2 -c 2 ") )
                if  response == 0:
                        print (f"UP {ip} Ping Succesful")
                        results_file.write(f"UP {ip} Ping Succesful" +  "\n")

                else:
                        print (f"DOWN {ip} ping Unsuccesful")
                        results_file.write(f"DOWN {ip} Ping Unsuccesful" + "\n")
```

В итоге в файле "resultat_ping.txt" должно быть:

UP "IP" Ping Succesful "Имя"

Прошу помощи

Comment: *if  response == 0: print (f"UP {ip} Ping Succesful")* Ага, разбежался! `TTL expired` тоже попадёт в Ping Succesful.

Comment: Вообщем убрав [1::2] из file.read().splitlines()  [1::2] и добавив в results_file.write(f"UP {ip} Ping Succesful" +  "\n") "\n"*2. в принципе получился читабельный вариант для себя. Пока оставлю так. буду дальше искать и пробовать. За советы благодарен.